# Inserting PHP into a HTML Button

Tags: php

How do I insert PHP code into a HTML Button? Here's what I have:

```
<input type="submit" value="Buy" onclick="
<?php
    $sq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Username='$usr'");
    $ar = mysql_fetch_array($sq);

    if ($ar['Beevals'] >= 250){
         mysql_query("UPDATE `accounts` SET `Beevals`=`Beevals`-250 WHERE Username='$usr'");
         mysql_query("UPDATE `accounts` SET `Skin`=`WorkersDream` WHERE Username='$usr'");

    }

?>
" />
```

But it doesn't work. So, I'm wandering how exactly can you insert PHP code into a HTML Button?

Comment: You can't. This needs to be done via ajax or form submit.

Comment: The things you have written is beyond any logic, please tell me what you want to do in brief, I will try to help you.

Comment: Hi dear, user921489 you need to learn basics of web development and server side scripting etc --

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Inserting PHP into an HTML button" doesn't make any sense.  HTML is for the client's browser, PHP executes on the server.

Take a look at the [PHP tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) to see a very basic example of how to make a form interact with PHP.  To crib from there:

**action.php**

```
Hi <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>.
You are <?php echo (int)$_POST['age']; ?> years old.

<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p>Your age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: How, exactly, would I do it then?

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be, how would I call a PHP Function via HTML Button?

Comment: @user921489 You are asking a very basic question, you need to read the tutorial and understand how server side scripting works.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a tutorial instead of just giving an answer, this is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. You should understand that PHP is purely a scripting language which runs **only** server side.

HTML is a client side markup language, which is sent from the server to the client. By the time that PHP has ran over your script, it has now left the server and is with the client. At which point no more PHP can execute without loading a new page again through another request.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways to go:

either process the form ON the server, meaning you'll need a form tag:

```
<form action="PHP_FILE.php" method="post/get">
<!-- INPUT TYPES -->
</form>
```

where method is either post or get (which means they'll be stored in the [superglobal vars](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php))

Using an ajax request, to send the request to a PHP file, which will handle the input, this is done using JavaScript's AJAX (or one of the many libraries for ease), I personally use [jquery](http://jquery.com/) for those sorts of things.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

On your way is no way to affect HTML with PHP.

You should use a Form <form></form>

For example:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["myButton"]))
{
    $sq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Username='$usr'");
    $ar = mysql_fetch_array($sq);

    if ($ar['Beevals'] >= 250){
         mysql_query("UPDATE `accounts` SET `Beevals`=`Beevals`-250 WHERE Username='$usr'");
         mysql_query("UPDATE `accounts` SET `Skin`=`WorkersDream` WHERE Username='$usr'");

    }

}
?>

<form action="readTheForm.php" method="get">
<input type="submit" name="myButton" value="Do it!"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the PHP-Code using AJAX or a normal request, defined by the action of the form-tag the button is in.

Comment: Is there any other way than AJAX?

Comment: Yes. `<form action="php_file.php"><input type="submit" value="Click"></form>` Insert your PHP-Code into the file `php_file.php` and click the button, your file will be opened. Insert `header("Location: html_file.html");` at the end of your php-file to get back to the page.